# One domain, two server Ip

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a domain like `example.com`, then in the DNS config I set:

```
A (HOST)
*     myProductionServerIp
@     myProductionServerIp

CNAME
www   @
```

So any query to example.com or www.example.com will address the production IP. I have a development server with another ip, is there a way to set something like dev.example.com that address the development ip?

Answer (score 1):

The `*` record will match any domain that is unmatched, the `@` is just a substitute for the $ORIGIN, have you even tried a

`dev   IN   A    1.2.3.4` record yet?

Comment: Are you saying this is the solution or are you just insulting the OP?

Comment: I'm asking if he's tried the simple solution, and what problems he experienced if he has..